# How to initialise an NSMutableString to avoid \n when parsing an xml?

Tags: xml-parsing, nsmutablestring

I have a little problem and i can not find how to solve it.

Actually, I parse an Xml file and when i pick up a value in a tag with the

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

I have as result : `LABELLEDEXPIRYPG = "Janv 2015\n    ";`

As you can see there is "\n and some spaces behind "Janv 2015"

I initialise my NSMutableString simply : `currentExpiry = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];`
and i use apendString to set NSMutableString :

```
 if ([currentElement isEqualToString:kExpiry]){
        [currentExpiry appendString:string];
    }
```

Please someone can help me to find a way to solve that ?

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
NSString *temp = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

Or you can use this line: very useful in XML parser:

```
NSString *temp = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Great, Really great ! the method stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] has worked !